# How to generate in Laravel Authorization header for s3 delete operation from angular?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, header, authorization, delete-file

I have configured disk **s3** in **Laravel 5.6** and **Angular 1.6** on client side.

I already have /vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php in my Laravel.

I need to generate only Header data in server side for this operation:

```
DELETE /ObjectName HTTP/1.1
Host: BucketName.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: date
Content-Length: length
Authorization: authorization string
```

(described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectDELETE.html)

for make something like this in my angular controller:

```
var deleteStorage = function () {

    $http.post('http://myserver.com/get-s3-auth-string').success(function (result) {

        $http.delete('http://mybucket.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/path/image.jpg',
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: result.header_string
                }
            }
            );

    });

};
```

And nothing else. How can i generate a valid authorization header for this operation?